# ¿"Así" y "así que" son intercambiables?

Tags: gramática

> Tienes que levantarte muy temprano así no vas a la escuela muy tarde.

> Estaba lloviendo a cántaros, así que fui a casa.

Me pregunto si son intercambiables. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Buenas, he corregido el título en tus dos últimas preguntas. No entiendo porque usas ">>" y "<<", esos símbolos no se emplean en el lenguaje común si no en los textos y expresiones científicas. Si te fijas en el lateral derecho, en el apartado "Related", verás que normalmente se emplean comillas para encuadrar la expresión por la que se pregunta.

Comment: @RubioRic puede que estuviera intentando usar las comillas españolas: _«Así» vs «Así que»_

Comment: @Charlie Tienes razón, seguramente es eso

Answer (score 3):

"[Así](https://dle.rae.es/as%C3%AD)" significa:

> 1. adv. dem. De esta o de esa manera

Cuando funciona como nexo entre dos oraciones, normalmente indica una **consecuencia intencionada** o una **consecuencia negativa que se podría evitar**. Por ejemplo:

- Tienes que levantarte muy temprano. Así no vas a la escuela muy tarde.
- Sale de fiesta todos los días. Así nunca va a completar sus estudios.

"Así que" significa

> 1. loc. conjunt. En consecuencia, de suerte que, por lo cual.

A diferencia de "así", normalmente se usa "así que" para hablar de una consecuencia de algo **que ya ha sucedido o que no se puede cambiar**. Por ejemplo:

- Estaba lloviendo a cántaros, así que fui a casa.
- Las fronteras seguirán cerradas durante todo el verano, así que no viajaré este año.

Hay definitivamente cierto solapamiento, y en muchos casos se pueden intercambiar las dos expresiones. Pero la diferencia se mantiene. Por ejemplo, en la frase

- Sale de fiesta todos los días. Así nunca va a completar sus estudios.

el hablante indica que tiene alguna esperanza de que la persona en cuestión cambie su actitud y deje de salir de fiesta con tanta frecuencia. En cambio, en la frase

- Sale de fiesta todos los días, así  que nunca va a completar sus estudios.

el hablante no tiene esa esperanza, y da por supuesto que la persona en cuestión seguirá saliendo de fiesta y no completará sus estudios.

Comment: el sustantivo "frontera" es femenino, no?

Comment: @sf_admin completamente cierto. Gracias por la corrección!